# WorksheetFunction.Match not working

Tags: vba, excel, match

Here is an excerpt from my data:

```
------+------+------+------+------+
      |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |
------+------+------+------+------+
1     | 10      20     25     30
2     | 152    181    195    210
```

and my code:

```
Dim xrng as range, yrng as range, offset as integer

set xrng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1")
set yrng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D2")

offset = WorksheetFunction.Match(23, xrng , 1) - 1
```

Why does running this result in a 1004 error: `Unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class`?  How can I fix it?

---

### EDIT: Detailed problem

Okay, I have written a function that does interpolation:

```
Public Function interpolate(intvalue_X As Double, xrange As range, yrange As range) As Double
....this is just an excerpt:
    Dim offst As Integer
    offst = WorksheetFunction.Match(intvalue_X, xrange, 1) - 1 'find the offset of the nearest value
---
End Function
```

With the following data and call, it works fine and returns the correct answer:
(don't mind the variables' who's declarations aren't shown - they have been declared at this point, it's just not copied)

[image]

```
Set intXrng = Sheets("Tables").range("B32:G32")
    If beltWidth >= 46 And beltWidth <= 122 And conveyerCenter >= 7.6 And conveyerCenter <= 152.4 Then 'dan kan jy die tabel gebruik
    m = interpolate(beltWidth, intXrng, Sheets("Tables").range("B44:G44"))
    c = interpolate(beltWidth, intXrng, Sheets("Tables").range("B45:G45"))
    powerX = m * conveyerCenter + c
Else
    MsgBox "Unable to use the power x-factor table.", vbCritical
End If
```

Now, when I use the same function, but with this data and call, it gives the error:

[image]

```
Set intXrng = Sheets("Tables").range("F4:I4")
angleSurcharge = 23
capacityTable = interpolate(angleSurcharge, intXrng, Sheets("Tables").range("F7:I7"))
```

Comment: In your VB editor options, set the option to require variable declaration.  This will preface all modules with Option Explicit.  Had you done so, you would have been alerted that your array in the Match function (xrange) had not been declared, and changed it to xrng.

Comment: I agree, it should be okay. I just have no idea why it doesn't work in the last case. If it really has a problem, it shouldn't work at all, but yet, it works every time, except for the last dataset.  I don't change xrange or angleSurcharge within the interpolate function at all.

Comment: You may want to do `Debug.Print intvalue_x` and Debug.Print xrange.Address(False, False)` and `For Each x In xrange Debug.Print x.Value Next` just before the `WokrsheetFunction.Match` so you can confirm that everything is what it should be

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52418/discussion-between-ripster-and-mierzen)

Comment: Here is the output:  
 23 
F4:I4
10
20
25
30
It seems fine to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are not stored as strings because they are in a table header. Table headers are always read as strings regardless of their format.

You can convert all values to the Doubles before passing it to Worksheet.Match to fix the bug.

```
Dim offst As Integer
Dim arry As Variant
ReDim arry(1 To 1, 1 To xrange.Columns.Count)

For i = 1 To xrange.Columns.Count
    arry(1, i) = CDbl(xrange.Cells(1, i).Value)
Next
offst = WorksheetFunction.Match(intvalue_X, arry, 1) - 1    'find the offset of the nearest value
```

Comment: @mierzen Having read your chat it is clear that 1) the lookup range values are strings, 2) they are strings because they are the header row of a table, 3) this is not changable while retaining the table structure.  I suggest you include this info in the answer.  It looks like the values are all whole numbers.  Using `Double` runs the risk that floating point precission issues _might_ cause false results.  I suggest use of `Long` to avoid this risk.

Comment: Also, you might consider using `Application.Match` rather than `WorksheetFunction` as it handles the edge case better, where the lookup value is > the max value in the range: returns an error _value_ rather than throwing a VBA error.  Test for it with `IsError` (you will need some other changes in your code to use this)

Comment: I used a `double` in my example because his function takes in `intvalue_x` as a `double` (misleading variable name). The worksheet data didn't appear to contain floating point values in any of the fields being passed though so it may be okay to use a `Long`.